# What kind of plant is this, and how do I care for it?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers

[image]

I was given this plant but can't remember the name. Can anyone identify this type of plant? Or maybe even know where to get information about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a [Celosia plant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celosia) It's also known as a "fire" flower because of its yellow, orange, and red colors. It can come in a couple of other colors. It's a full sun flower that drops its seeds so it can overtake a garden if you don't collect the seeds (or just plant it separately) "so they say". I have planted them successfully with impatiens and they did great... Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks @Brittany. Just one more question; do you think I should plant it in the garden now? I live in area that's mid way through the fall/autumn season and just coming into winter. We'll probably get some frost. Also, my soil is a little dry.

Comment: No it likes warm/hot dry weather (will do ok in humidity if warm)... But it can do ok inside if u have a window with full sun... This plant does the best in desert type climates usually so I wouldn't subject it to cold

Comment: I don't know what other choices you have where you live, but I grow them each year with things like petunias, marigolds, snapdragons and geranium. When it gets top-heavy like that, or if you want to avoid a lot of seeds, just pinch off the big flower, and all those little buds you see will have an easier time growing. You can also control how "bushy" you want it to look in the same way.

Comment: It's also an annual. Once it does back, unless it's pollinated and goes to seed. That's it. These grew well in Sarasota FL.